# как изменить под динамический массив?

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

```
using namespace std;

void ProbelVoid(char *str)
{

    char *str1=new char [512];
    int  i = 0;
    for (char* a = str, *b = str1; *a; ++a, ++b, i++)
    {
        for (; *a == ' ' && *(a + 1) == ' '; a++);

        *b = *a;
    }
    str1[i] = '\0';
    strcpy_s(str, strlen(str1), str1);

}

int main()
{


    ifstream in("1.txt");
    if (!in)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка: не могу открыть входной файл ";
        system("pause");
        return-1;

    }

    char *str=new char[512];
    in.getline(str, 512);

    cout << "Изначальная строка\n" << str;
    ProbelVoid(str);
    cout << "\n\nИзменённая строка\n" << str;
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    out << str;
    cout << endl;     
    out.close();
    in.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

не могу переделать под динамический массив, чтобы из файла без проблем можно было любого размера текст использовать в программе ( удаляет лишние пробелы)

Comment: А Вам нужно именно на си писать? Почему не используете `std::string`? (о том, что память нужно освобождать, я уже молчу)

Comment: я не знаю как определить длину исходной строки из файла, чтобы создать динамический массив и его передать в функцию, про удаление я знаю, просто еще не дошел

Comment: читайте просто построчно с файла в `std::string` с помощью `std::getline`. Все автоматом будет выделено.

Answer (score 2):

В С++ уже имеется класс, который инкапсулирует в себе динамический массив символов. Это класс `std::string`.

Для чтения из потока строк можно использовать стандартную функцию `std::getline`.

Также в C++ имеется стандартный алгоритм `std::unique` который позволяет исключить из строки повторяющиеся символы.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как использовать указанные средства. В этой программе вместо файла для простоты используется строковый поток, а вывод осуществляется также не в файл, а на консоль. Программу не сложно модифицировать, заменив строковый поток и консоль на входной и выходной файлы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

int main() 
{
    std::istringstream is( "Hello,      World!\nI   am learning   C++" );

    std::string s;

    while ( std::getline( is, s ) && !s.empty() )
    {
        auto it = std::unique( s.begin(), s.end(),
                               []( char c1, char c2 )
                               {
                                   return ( c1 == ' ' || c1 == '\t' ) && ( c1 == c2 );
                               });

        s.erase( it, s.end() );                            

        std::cout << s << std::endl;                     
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль

```
Hello, World!
I am learning C++
```

Как видно из вывода, повторяющиеся знаки пробелов исключены из входной строки.

Если входной файл может содержать пустые строки, то второе условие из цикла while следует убрать. Например,

```
while ( std::getline( is, s ) )
```

Но можно это условие включить для записи результирующих строк в выходной файл, то есть можно не писать пустые строки в выходной файл. Например,

```
    if ( !s.empty() ) std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы вам не решить вашу задачу проще и короче?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char cur, last = 0;
    while(cin.get(cur))
    {
        if (isspace(cur) && isspace(last)) continue;
        cout << (last = cur);
    }
}
```

Из всего ввода выбрасываются дублируемые пробельные символы:

```
qwtdcas jahsghj   hbdjhbhjd      dyuygd yeduy  tyuyd
qwtdcas jahsghj hbdjhbhjd dyuygd yeduy tyuyd
^Z
```

Длина строки совершенно неважна :)

Если нужно ограничиться *одной* строкой - после

```
        cout << (last = cur);
```

добавьте

```
        if (cur == '\n') break;
```